# How do i assert that all elements in a list are in a given range

Tags: java, list, selenium

I have tried to compare all elements in a list that have this locator :
70.000

I have tried this using AssertJ but it does not work:

```
 List<WebElement> listaPret = driver.findElements(By.className("pret-mare"));

 for (int i = 0; i < listaPret.size(); i++){
      assertThat(i).isBetween(50.000,80.000);
 }
```

Adding the webpage where I try to check this 
https://www.imobiliare.ro/vanzare-apartamente/timisoara?id=6923228

I am very new to selenium and automation testing including programing so please be pacient with me :D

Comment: why not just assertThat(listaPret.size()).isBetween(50.000,80.000); ?

Comment: Define "it does not work". What happens when you compile/run this code, and what do you expect to happen instead? How could a web element be in a numeric range? What does that mean? It makes as much sense to me as "this banana should be between 1 and 10".

Comment: When I compile this code it returns java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting:
 <0>
to be between:
 [50000, 80000], so I guess I should convert every element in the list to integer and compare if it is contained in that specified range, is that correct?

Comment: Hello! Are you trying to check that the text for the elements are all between 50.000 and 80.000? How is `70.000` a locator? It appears that you're asserting that your index, `i`, is between `50.000` and `80.000`. Which will fail during the first check because `i` is `0`.

Comment: No. That happens when you **run** the code. I misread the code: you're checking that the index in the loop (i, which starts at 0) is in the range 50, 80. That is not the case. So the test fails. What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: The values in the list are prices on that page and I try to see if all prices displayed are in that range from 50.000 and 80.000

Comment: How about this? `for (WebElement item : listaPret) { assertThat(item.getText()).isBetween(50000,80000); }` Note: You'll have to convert the string to a number, so this is more conceptual than something you can compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
 List<WebElement> listaPret = driver.findElements(By.className("pret-mare"));

 assertThat(listaPret.size()).isBetween(50.000,80.000);
```

if you're trying to get numbers from listaPret then use this:

```
 List<WebElement> listaPret = driver.findElements(By.className("pret-mare"));

 for (int i = 0; i < listaPret.size(); i++){
      double price = Double.parseDouble(listaPret.get(i).getText()); 
      assertThat(price).isBetween(50.000,80.000);
 }
```

As suggested by @mrfreester using for each loop to be safer (also better looking) :

```
 List<WebElement> listaPret = driver.findElements(By.className("pret-mare"));

 for (WebElement item : listaPret) { 
      double price = Double.parseDouble(item.getText()); 
      assertThat(price).isBetween(50.000,80.000);
 }
```

Comment: This will check that the selector find between 50 and 80 elements (although I think they really meant 50000 and 80000 for their comparison), while I think the OP is asking to assert the values of each of the elements. That being said, it's not totally clear.

Comment: Upvoted, although I'd suggest a foreach loop since this is just iterating the entire list. `for (WebElement item : listaPret)`  and then inside the loop `Double.parseDouble(item.getText())`

Comment: @mrfreester done.

Comment: This worked perfectly I have used the code above but using a foreach statement , thank you all for the help.